# How to make Amazon Kindle Text to Speech skip over some text

Tags: html, text-to-speech, kindle

I am deploying some books to Amazon Kindle. The text has lots of numeric citations links at paragraph and sentence ends. How do I make kindle text to speech skip over those and not read them out lout. I tried to put them in  element, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: There is no way as of now.

Answer (score -1):

How about a CSS class which specifies "speak: none;" for these items?